# nginx вместо конкретной страницы выдает 404

Tags: nginx

Пытаюсь установить свою страницу для ошибки 503. Nginx возвращает стандартную или 404. По адресу /var/www/zzz/data/www/my_site.ru/maintenance.html страница есть. Если напрямую её открывать, открывается. Конфиг:

server {
                if (-f /etc/nginx/maintenance.file) {
                        return 503;
                }

```
            server_name my_site.ru;
            listen 8.8.8.8;
            disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path/$subdomain;
            set $root_path /var/www/zzz/data/www/my_site.ru;
            set $subdomain "";
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block;";
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
            add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
            add_header X-XSRF-Protected 1;

            error_page 503 @maintenance;

           if ( $http_user_agent ~* (nmap|nikto|wikto|sf|sqlmap|bsqlbf|w3af|acunetix|havij|appscan) ) {
              return 403;
           }


            location @maintenance {
                    rewrite ^(.*)$ /var/www/zzz/data/www/my_site.ru/maintenance.html break;
            }
            location ~* ^$ {
                    root $root_path/$subdomain;
                    access_log /var/www/nginx-logs/zzz isp;
                    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/my_site.ru.access.log ;
                    error_page 404 = @fallback;
            }
            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://8.8.8.8:81;
                    proxy_redirect http://8.8.8.8:81/ /;
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            }
            location ~* ^/(webstat|awstats|webmail|myadmin|pgadmin)/ {
                    proxy_pass http://8.8.8.8:81;
                    proxy_redirect http://8.8.8.8:81/ /;
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            }
            location @fallback {
                    proxy_pass http://8.8.8.8:81;
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            }
            location ^~ /webstat/ {
                    auth_basic "Restricted area";
                    auth_basic_user_file /var/www/zzz/data/etc/3227648.passwd;
                    try_files $uri @fallback;
            }
            include /usr/local/ispmgr/etc/nginx.inc;
            if ($host ~* ^((.*).my_site.ru)$) {
                    set $subdomain ../$1;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте по-проще, в nginx конфиге:

```
error_page 500 503 =503 /var/www/zzz/data/www/my_site.ru/maintenance.html;
```